# Trouble sending HTTP GET Request from Arduino to Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, arduino, raspberry-pi3

I am running Incredible PBX on a Raspberry Pi3. I have an Arduino MEGA that sends an HTTP GET Request to the Raspberry Pi. Arduino sends three variables, ext, calleerid, & room and calls a PHP file on the Raspberry Pi to write values to MySql. I can see the GET request in the Apache2 access log file on Raspberry Pi, but the PHP file does not run. Appreciate any suggestions.

I've previously had this working on a Raspberry Pi model A, but now that I'm using a newer version I cannot figure out why the PHP file does not load and write values to the database.

The Arduino Code is -

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("-> Connected and sending HTTP Request");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.print( "GET /add_data.php?"); //THIS SHOULD BE add_data.php
    client.print("ext=");
    client.print( extn );

    client.print("&&");
    client.print("room=");
    client.print( room );

    client.print("&&");
    client.print("callerid=");
    client.print( callerId2 );

    client.println( " HTTP/1.1");
    client.print( "Host: " );
    client.println(server);
    client.println( "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );     
    client.println( "Connection: close" );
    client.println();
    client.println();
    client.stop();
    //Serial.print ("Room = " + room);

    Serial.println ("HTTP Request proceesed and sent!");
    Serial.println ("Database queries in process");
   }
   else {
    // you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("--> connection failed/n");
   }
```

PHP Code is -

`

```
// Prepare the SQL statement
$SQL = "INSERT INTO test.newdata (ext ,callerid ,room) VALUES ('".$_GET["ext"]."','".$_GET ["callerid"]."','".$_GET["room"]."')";   
$SQL1 = "INSERT INTO test.room (room) VALUES ('".$_GET["room"]."')";              

// Execute SQL statement
mysql_query($SQL);
mysql_query($SQL1);
include("select_room.php");


// Go to the review_data.php (optional)
header("Location: Site_2/review_data.php");
?>`
```

The Apache2 access log file shows the GET request -

x.x.x.x - - [13/Apr/2019:22:50:29 -0400] "GET /Site_2/review_data.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1538 "http://x.x.x.x/Site_2/review_data.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"
x.x.x.x - - [13/Apr/2019:22:50:52 -0400] "GET /add_data.php?ext=5000&&room=110&&callerid=110+Config+Test" 400 0 "-" "-"
10.1.11.200 - - [13/Apr/2019:22:51:14 -0400] "GET /Site_2/review_data.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1538 "http://192.168.50.123/Site_2/review_data.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using the REST Architecture in a wrong way. Actually you use GET to insert new data instead of POST type request.

However, I have not tried your code but the problem could be double && instead of single &.

Moreover, you have to debug your PHP code with error_log($variable_name) to see if you receive the values from GET correctly.

Tip: When you work with REST calls try to use POSTMAN software to simulate the REST CALL and see the response

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try those things.